# How MACA will behave in this situations?

Tags: access-control

I am trying to understand how collisions are resolved in the MACA protocol when there are three stations - A, B, and C with the following reachability:

- A can only communicate with B
- B can communicate with A and C
- C can only communicate with B

I understand that if two stations send RTS frames simultaneously to each other, they will collide and each station will back off a random amount of time before retrying the RTS.

However, I am unsure of how collisions would be resolved in the following scenario:

Station C sends an RTS frame to B.
At the same time, Station B sends an RTS frame to A

Comment: In an RTS Collison like that, no CTS would be received by C from B, indicating a collision.